# Is it possible to generate an unsigned Xcode archive with Titanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

We've build a Titanium application for a client, but the client wants to be able to sign the application themselves. To do this they requested an unsigned Xcode archive. We're unable to generate a valid archive using Titanium.

We've tried running the xcodebuild command on Xcode project that's generated by Titanium. Something like:

```
xcodebuild -workspace <projectName>.xcworkspace -scheme <projectName> -configuration Release clean archive -archivePath buildArchive/<projectName>.xcarchive CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO
```

But that generates an invalid archive, so we suspect that Titanium is doing something extra to generate a valid archive.

We've also tried building the app for distribution and editing the generated archive manually. But we're unable to fully remove the signing from the archive. The entitlements still exist with wrong id after removing the _codeSigning directory and embedded.mobileprovision profile.

Is it maybe possible to write a cli hook to add the CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO variable during the app build?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it's actually possible to add the CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED variable using a cli hook.

```
exports.init = function (logger, config, cli, appc) {
  cli.on('build.ios.xcodebuild', {
    pre: function (data, next) {
      if (this.deployType === 'production') {
        data.args[1].push("CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO");            
      }
      next(null, data);
    }
  });
};
```

Now I can generate unsigned archives.

Comment: it should even be possible without the hook: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52589151/resign-ios-application-ipa-file-without-changing-bundleid